# Redirect root to page for jquery tabs

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, jquery-tools, jquery-jscrollpane

I've got a site using jQuery Tools tabs and Ajax. It works fine if you start out at the home page:

http://bdbcreative.com/home.htm

Click on any of the tabs and you get the extended Ajax address, which is what client wants and seems to be necessary for jScrollPane to work (http://bdbcreative.com/home.htm#web-design.htm).

But if someone just enters the domain - http://bdbcreative.com - "home.htm" never gets written and I end up with a URL like http://bdbcreative.com/#web-design.htm, which breaks jScrollPane.

I'm thinking I can use .htaccess to fix this, but I can't figure out the syntax. Can someone point me in the right direction. For consistency's sake, I'd like to have any site root URLs (http://bdbcreative.com or http:www.bdbcreative.com/ etc.) redirect to the home.htm address (i.e., http://bdbcreative.com/home.htm)

Thanks - Joe

Answer (score 0):

After trying umpteen thousand examples, I found one that did what I needed.

For the .htacess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.bdbcreative.com/index.htm [R=301,L]
```

Hope this helps someone else.

Best - Joe